# Possible ways of distributing?

Tags: permutations

What is the possible ways of distributing 10 identical things among 6 children

My solution is "out of 10 identical things 6 can be given to 6 children in only one way,since the things are identical,Now the remaining 4 identical things can be distributed among 6 children in n+r-1cr-1 i.e 9c5"

But i am not getting the answer

Please explain

Comment: Each child can  get more than one of the items, so basically you are trying  to find the solutions of $\sum_{i=1}^6 x_i = 10$, where the $x_i$ are non-negative. This is done via  stars and bars, which you should read up.

Comment: If $^9C_5$ is not giving the answer, maybe a child(ren) getting nothing is allowed.